# Struggling with snapshot.data.data()["example field"]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a stream builder to see realtime changes that happen in my document. I don't know if they've updated the code again. Before it was snapshot.data.data()["example field"]["..."], now I don't know.

Here is my sample code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grizzlyclips/Models/square-create-customer.dart';

class GrizzlyAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GrizzlyAccountState createState() => _GrizzlyAccountState();
}

class _GrizzlyAccountState extends State<GrizzlyAccount> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  var firstname = "", lastname = "", code = "", state = "details";
  var email = "", mobile = "", password = "", repassword = "";
  var companyname = "", username = "", countrycode = "";
  var birthDay = "", birthMonth = "", birthYear = "";
  var addressline1 = "", addressline2 = "", addressline3 = "";
  var administrativedistrictlevel1 = "";
  var administrativedistrictlevel2 = "";
  var administrativedistrictlevel3 = "";
  var country = "", locality = "", organization = "", postalcode = "";
  var sublocality = "", sublocality2 = "", sublocality3 = "", note = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xffb76e23),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(height: 50),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Grizzly Account",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                  color: Color(0xffC79159),
                                  fontSize: 30),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(height: 40),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                          ),
                          Container(height: 20),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Loading Details",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }

          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xffb76e23),
            body: GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTap: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(height: 50),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Grizzly Account",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                  color: Color(0xffC79159),
                                  fontSize: 30),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(height: 40),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffC79159)),
                              height: 80,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.pin_drop_rounded,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(addressline1,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                        Text(locality,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                                  // Container(
                                  //   width: 80,
                                  //   child: Icon(
                                  //     Icons.chevron_right,
                                  //     color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                  //     size: 40,
                                  //   ),
                                  // ),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                              // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffC79159)),
                              height: 80,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.person,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("$firstname $lastname",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                        Text(username,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                                  // Container(
                                  //   width: 80,
                                  //   child: Icon(
                                  //     Icons.chevron_right,
                                  //     color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                  //     size: 40,
                                  //   ),
                                  // ),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                              // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffC79159)),
                              height: 80,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.email,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(email,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                        // Text(locality,
                                        //     style: TextStyle(
                                        //         fontSize: 12,
                                        //         fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                        //         color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                                  // Container(
                                  //   width: 80,
                                  //   child: Icon(
                                  //     Icons.chevron_right,
                                  //     color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                  //     size: 40,
                                  //   ),
                                  // ),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                              // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffC79159)),
                              height: 80,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.phone,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(mobile,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                        // Text(locality,
                                        //     style: TextStyle(
                                        //         fontSize: 12,
                                        //         fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                        //         color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                                  // Container(
                                  //   width: 80,
                                  //   child: Icon(
                                  //     Icons.chevron_right,
                                  //     color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                  //     size: 40,
                                  //   ),
                                  // ),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                              // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffC79159)),
                              height: 80,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.date_range,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                            "$birthDay - $birthMonth - $birthYear",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                        // Text(locality,
                                        //     style: TextStyle(
                                        //         fontSize: 12,
                                        //         fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                        //         color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                                  // Container(
                                  //   width: 80,
                                  //   child: Icon(
                                  //     Icons.chevron_right,
                                  //     color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                  //     size: 40,
                                  //   ),
                                  // ),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                              // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffC79159)),
                              height: 80,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.business_center,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8),
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("$companyname",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                                color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                        // Text(locality,
                                        //     style: TextStyle(
                                        //         fontSize: 12,
                                        //         fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                        //         color: Color(0xffF2E9D8))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(height: 20),
                                Container(height: 20),
                                Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 200,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                      color: Color(0xffF2E9D8)),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Update Details",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                            fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(height: 20),
                                Container(
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "back",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: "AlfaSlabOne",
                                            color: Color(0xffF2E9D8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I know that my code is very messy, but I'm looking to clean it soon!

Here's a couple of screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Great News! I've found a workaround for anyone who is struggling with this same situation as well.

1. Encode your snapshot data with Json.encode().
2. Decode your encoded JSON data with JsonDecode.
3. Then you can use ["example field"] to present the data you want in a text widget or any other widget.

Here is a snippet:

`jsonDecode(json.encode(snapshot.data!.data()))["example field"]`

It works now for the app, here's a couple of screenshots:

[image]

[image]

And there's no more errors, remember to use: `<DocumentSnapshot>` when using `StreamBuilder` so that you get the correct IntelliSense to help you & so that you don't get red lines.

If you're looking to do a document query, set snapshot data a map like this in a variable instead of decoding and encoding. Here's an example:

`Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;`

This should help with the issues like timestamps from Firestore.

I hope that it helps!